# Determine age of Charcoal from Current Decay Rate? (Differential Equations)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In this differential equation problem, I am given the following information:

in $1950$, a piece of charcoal from a roof beam gave a count of $4.09$ dis/min/g, living wood gave $6.68$ disintegrations, estimate when the charcoal was formed.

I can't figure this out. I start using the formula:

$$
\frac{dN}{dt} = -kN
$$

where $k$ is the decay constant and $N$ is the amount of charcoal present. Solving this differential equation I get:

$$
N(t) = N_0e^{-kt}
$$

where $N_0$ is the initial amount of charcoal and $t$ is time in years. I then use my given decay rate and the formula I just found and plug those back into the diff eq like so:

$$
-4.09 = -kN_0e^{-kT}
$$

$T$ now being the change in time from the formation of the charcoal to $1950$.

I'm stuck, and I have no idea how to find k, which I think is what I need to solve the problem.

Comment: @Armando j18eos Thanks!

Comment: Hint: use the 6.68 ... how long has the living wood decayed?